# Sanitizing data to use within quotes & within URL

Tags: php, javascript, encoding, sanitization

If I want to put a value between single quotes in Javascript how can I sanitize/encode it so that any quotes in the value doesn't cause issues?

I also want to then use this value in a query string which I will then be passing to PHP.

Whatever is used I need to be able to decode it back to it's normal value with PHP.

**Example:**

```
$foo = "Hey, what's up!?"; // PHP

getGrades('<?=$foo?>'); // JS Function

function getGrades(var) {

        // Set file to get results from..
        var loadUrl = "ajax_files/get_grades.php";

        // Set data string
        var dataString = 'grade=' + var;

        // Run the AJAX request
        runAjax(loadUrl, dataString);          

}

function runAjax(loadUrl, dataString) {

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: loadUrl,
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'html',
        error: ajaxError,
        success: function(response) {
            someFunction(response);
        }
    });    

}

// get_grades.php file

$grade = $_GET['grade']; // We now want this value to be it's normal value of "Hey, what's up!?";
```

Comment: Can you add an example ?

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript

Comment: @MihaiIorga Added example.

Comment: Use Quentin response and change the var `var` because it's reserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `getGrades('<?=$foo?>'); // JS Function`

`json_encode` will make a string JavaScript safe (and quote it).

```
getGrades(<?php echo json_encode($foo); ?>);
```

---

> I also want to then use this value in a query string which I will then be passing to PHP.

Pass `data:` an *object*, not a string. jQuery will handle the escaping for you.

```
var dataString = { grade: var }; // Rename the variable too
```

Comment: `var` was cribbed from the original code. Hopefully it is just a poor example.

Comment: Btw... I won't need to do any decoding with PHP once I get the variable from the query string right!?

Comment: Assuming you use `$_GET` to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you have concatenating with single quoted string it will not be an issue. Only thing left is when you use it in query string. In that case You should use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Also change your `var` to something else. `var` is a keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: @Brett — Nothing. PHP will decode it before populating `$_GET`.